# LINQ / C# SubQuery

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, subquery

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id;
    public string CustomerName;
    public DateTime OrderDate;
    public List<OrderLine> Lines;
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public decimal Quantity;
    public decimal UnitPrice;
    public Product Product;
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public decimal DefaultUnitPrice;
}
```

I'm getting pretty confused as how to do this query, I'm trying to display the `CustomerName` ascending, depending on the total of the orders.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CustomerName Ascending depending on the total of the Orders` What's that?

Comment: Alsom what do you mean by *depending on the total of the Orders*? Two sorting attributes, CustomerName and count(Orders)?

Comment: Total order amount in money, total number of orders?

Comment: Total amount in money. Thanks for the replies,I might have managed to get it right.

Comment: So when you realise which is the solution, please accept it. And welcome to StackOverflow! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from o in orders
    select new {
    o.CustomerName, 
    Total = o.Lines.Sum(x=>x.UnitPrice*x.Quantity)}
    ).OrderBy(x=>x.CustomerName).ThenBy(x=>x.Total);;
```

Edit: fixed total sum

Comment: Except you may want to multiply the unit price by the quantity. (Depending on what the OP is actually trying to get.)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
order.OrderBy(x => x.Lines.Sum(q => q.Quantity * q.UnitPrice));
```